# isolated storage for windows phone 8?

Tags: isolatedstorage, windows-phone-8

i need to create isolated storage for my windows phone app, it is a business app that shows you all your business documents, and from there you can reject and accept the business documents, now what my problem is i have no idea where to start with isolate storage? i have been through google, but it does not make any sense, so if anyone can send me a link or tutorial it will be awesome, and how can i make the isolated storage in my app.xaml file so i can use it over and over again?

[this is the link that gave me basic understanding , but it is all on buttonclick?](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/15/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-15-isolated-storage/)

Comment: I just wrote a free isolated storage dll. Very easy to use http://www.anthonyrussell.info/postpage.php?name=47

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a pretty comprehensive example at the msdn page for [isoloated storage file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). If you need to double check some of the files that you've placed there, there is [isolated storage explorer tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286408%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) that comed with the sdk.

Comment: lol i totaly forgot to mark this question! but yes your links did help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried IsoStoreSpy ? It supports both WP7 and WP8

It works well on my WP8 emulator, too

See here http://isostorespy.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

> public static IsolatedStorageSettings appSetting = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

if (appSetting.Keys.Count == 0)
    appSetting.Add("key",value);

if (appSetting.Keys.Count > 0)
    appSetting.Remove("TEACHER");

if (appSetting.Contains("key"))

...